# fct_lump and fct_count on all columns which are factors

Tags: r, list, select

I'm pretty new in R and a little stuck on finding an more elegant way to answer the question in my online course.

I have a dataset with 69 columns, some of them are factors.
1. I want to display all variables that have a factor level with less than 30 occurrences
2. I want to lump all factors so that the 100 most common factors remain, the others are lumped

I think I might have the solution, for a single column, but my issue is I cant get it together as a function. I think I can use the map function, but this gives me a list as an output. And I want to keep it a dataset.

What I did so far:

1.

```
> rawdata10<-rawdata9 %>% map(~ countFactors(.))  lapply(rawdata10,  FUN = '[', 2)
```

With that I can access the second column of the list, but i have issues to select all variables that are smaller

```
rawdata10[which(sapply(rawdata10, '[[', 2) < 100)]
```

It says  > (list) Objekt kann nicht nach 'double' umgewandelt werden

2. I tried the second with the map() function. But here a got a list instead of my dataset i hat before and i do not know how to work with it. Is there a possibility to convert it back to a dataset, or not even make a list out of it?

lumpFactors <- function(col){

```
if(is.factor(col)){
    fct_lump(col,n=100)

  }else{
    NULL
  }
}
rawdata10<-rawdata9 %>% map(~ lumpFactors(.))
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please fix typos (occurance for occurrence, facotr for factor, etc.) and translate the German sentence to English. That's easy enough using Google translate, but I suspect you know enough English to do it without any help. It seems to mean "(list) object can't be converted to 'double'" but it's nice not to have to figure that out. We welcome non-English-speakers but this is an English-language site.

Comment: You can use `mutate_if` with `is.factor` as the predicate